# Process crashes during creation of RoboGuice injector, if there is a mocked instance in any module

Tags: java, android, eclipse, roboguice

I have a problem with using RoboGuice and AndroidMock frameworks in unit testing.
I've created a simple project to show my problem. Here I create a mocked instance and register it in the RoboGuice.
But the process crashes between the "setUp()" and "test01()" methods.
As I guess, actually the process crashes when the Injector is created, if any module has a mocked instance inside.

If I replace the mocked instance with an instance of a class that implements the interface then everything works fine.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Here is my test code:

```
public class testInjectMock extends RoboUnitTestCase<MyApplication> {
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        InterfaceToMock instance = AndroidMock.createNiceMock(InterfaceToMock.class);           AndroidMock.expect(instance.SimpleMethod()).andStubReturn("Hello!");            
        MyModule myMockModule = new MyModule();
        myMockModule.setMockedInstance(instance);//Comment this string to get into the test01() method          
        MyApplication.setMyModule(myMockModule);
        super.setUp();
    }
    public void test01() {
        //It never comes here
    }
}
```

Module source code:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractAndroidModule {
        protected InterfaceToMock mockedInstance;
        public void setMockedInstance(InterfaceToMock mockedInstance) {
            this.mockedInstance = mockedInstance;
        }
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            if(mockedInstance != null)
                bind(InterfaceToMock.class).toInstance(mockedInstance);
        }
    }
```

The logcat output:

```
05-23 16:17:07.135: INFO/DEBUG(27): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.1-update1/ECLAIR/35983:eng/test-keys'
05-23 16:17:07.135: INFO/DEBUG(27): pid: 2025, tid: 2031  >>> InjectMock.test <<<
05-23 16:17:07.145: INFO/DEBUG(27): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000
05-23 16:17:07.155: INFO/DEBUG(27):  r0 0011b218  r1 43d1caa0  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
05-23 16:17:07.155: INFO/DEBUG(27):  r4 43d1caa0  r5 0011b218  r6 451c0e30  r7 4000a958
05-23 16:17:07.155: INFO/DEBUG(27):  r8 ad00f380  r9 00138de0  10 426bda34  fp 00138de0
05-23 16:17:07.155: INFO/DEBUG(27):  ip 00000002  sp 451c0dc0  lr ad05ad1d  pc ad05a804  cpsr 00000030
05-23 16:17:07.295: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #00  pc 0005a804  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.305: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #01  pc 0005ad18  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.305: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #02  pc 00054a4a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.315: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #03  pc 00013f58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.325: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #04  pc 00019888  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.335: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #05  pc 00018d5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.335: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #06  pc 0004d6d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.345: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #07  pc 0004d702  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.355: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #08  pc 00041c78  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.365: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #09  pc 00010000  /system/lib/libc.so
05-23 16:17:07.365: INFO/DEBUG(27):          #10  pc 0000fad4  /system/lib/libc.so
05-23 16:17:07.375: INFO/DEBUG(27): code around pc:
05-23 16:17:07.385: INFO/DEBUG(27): ad05a7f4 ffff5ae0 fffe57c4 6801b5f8 6a8b1c05 
05-23 16:17:07.385: INFO/DEBUG(27): ad05a804 1c30681e ff5ef7ff 28001c04 6840d018 
05-23 16:17:07.395: INFO/DEBUG(27): ad05a814 d0152800 37101c27 d0112f00 f7ff1c28 
05-23 16:17:07.395: INFO/DEBUG(27): code around lr:
05-23 16:17:07.405: INFO/DEBUG(27): ad05ad0c f7ff1c20 bd10ff7b 6804b510 fd70f7ff 
05-23 16:17:07.405: INFO/DEBUG(27): ad05ad1c 28001c01 f7ffd102 e002f859 f7ff1c20 
05-23 16:17:07.415: INFO/DEBUG(27): ad05ad2c bd10ff6d 4c24b5f0 1c0d1c06 48236a81 
05-23 16:17:07.425: INFO/DEBUG(27): stack:
05-23 16:17:07.425: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0d80  43d20870  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
05-23 16:17:07.425: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0d84  00000354  
05-23 16:17:07.425: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0d88  00000022  
05-23 16:17:07.425: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0d8c  ad043693  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.425: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0d90  ad07ff50  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.425: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0d94  00000024  
05-23 16:17:07.425: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0d98  00000354  
05-23 16:17:07.425: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0d9c  ad0170ac  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.425: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0da0  00000000  
05-23 16:17:07.435: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0da4  afe0f2c0  /system/lib/libc.so
05-23 16:17:07.435: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0da8  ad080c00  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.435: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0dac  00000002  
05-23 16:17:07.435: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0db0  00000354  
05-23 16:17:07.445: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0db4  43d20870  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
05-23 16:17:07.445: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0db8  df002777  
05-23 16:17:07.455: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0dbc  e3a070ad  
05-23 16:17:07.455: INFO/DEBUG(27): #00 451c0dc0  00000000  
05-23 16:17:07.455: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0dc4  43d1caa0  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
05-23 16:17:07.455: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0dc8  451c0e38  
05-23 16:17:07.455: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0dcc  451c0e30  
05-23 16:17:07.455: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0dd0  4000a958  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/zygote/0 (deleted)
05-23 16:17:07.455: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0dd4  ad05ad1d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-23 16:17:07.465: INFO/DEBUG(27): #01 451c0dd8  417a0b5c  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex
05-23 16:17:07.475: INFO/DEBUG(27):     451c0ddc  ad054a4f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

Comment: Additional information:
It is possible to create injector with a mocked instance in any module.
I've successfully created Injector in "test01()" method. 
But if the Injector is created by the RoboUnitTestCase the app is crashed.

Comment: The RoboUnitTestCase source http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/source/browse/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/test/RoboUnitTestCase.java?r=c56f24a7484ef75f7ffd8ab2177d4115fa7ce548 says "Make sure you use one of the @*Test annotations AND begin your testcase's name with "test"" but your Setup isn't annotated `@Before` and your test isn't annotated `@Test`...

Comment: It seems that it is not directly a java problem (`signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 0000000`). Could you try with an other firmware version (emulator or device) ?

Comment: Could you give us the definition of the interface InterfaceToMock, so we can reproduce the exact behaviour of AndroidMock.createNiceMock.

Comment: If one of A's was good for you, could you accept it? Q is still open.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, if there's an issue with the setup steps for RoboGuice & unit testing, you can get this sort of error.  No magic short answer, but rather a set of steps to follow exactly.

BTW, you're using RoboGuice 1.1 - AbstractAndroidModule & RoboUnitTest no longer exist in RoboGuice 2.0.  RoboGuice 1.1 is deprecated, so best overall solution is to move to newest version according to these instructions [Upgrading to 2.0](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/UpgradingTo20).

However, just in case you're attached to RoboGuice 1.1, here's some steps to follow:

- Don't have inconsistent generated code/build files after refactoring/changing package names etc.  Delete generated code, do a Clean & Build, even recreate a new project and copy source files in.
- Have your app code in one project (RoboGuice dependent, Instrumentation/RoboUnitTestCase/AndroidMock independent).  You app code project has within lib: guice-2.0-no_aop.jar and roboguice-1.1.2.jar.
- Have your unit test code in another project that references it (RoboGuice independent, Instrumentation/RoboUnitTestCase/AndroidMock independent).  Instructions here [Before You Get Started](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/Testing).  Your test code project has within lib: AndroidMockGenerator.jar.
- In your app project, your App + Module classes look something like this:

  ```
  package com.mypackage;

  import android.app.Instrumentation;
  import android.content.Context;

  public class MyApplication extends roboguice.application.RoboApplication {

  static MyModule myModule;    

  // this constructor usually called by app
  public MyApplication(Context context) {
      super();
      attachBaseContext(context);
  }
  // This constructor called by unit tests.  This is unfortunately small amount of 
  // 'abstraction leakage' of unit test needs into app code.
  public MyApplication(Instrumentation instrumentation) {
      super();
      attachBaseContext(instrumentation.getContext());
  }    
  public static void setModule(MyModule module) {
      MyApplication.myModule = module;
  }   
  public static MyModule getModule() {
      return MyApplication.myModule;
  }   
  }
  ```

  And

  ```
  package com.mypackage;

  public class MyModule extends roboguice.config.AbstractAndroidModule {
  // this will be injected
  protected UsefulObject myUsefulInstance;    

  public void setUsefulObject(UsefulObject usefulInstance) {
      this.myUsefulInstance = usefulInstance;
  }    
  public UsefulObject getUsefulObject() {
      return this.myUsefulInstance;
  }    

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
      bind(UsefulObject.class).toInstance(myUsefulInstance);
  }
  ```

  }
- In your test project, your test case class looks something like this:

  ```
  import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;    
  import com.mypackage.MyApplication;    
  import com.mypackage.MyModule;    
  import com.mypackage.UsefulObject;    
   //import com.mypackage.UsefulObjectSimpleImplementation;    
  import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.MediumTest;    
  import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;    
  import com.google.android.testing.mocking.AndroidMock;    
  import roboguice.test.RoboUnitTestCase;

  public class TestMyModule extends RoboUnitTestCase<MyApplication> {

  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
      UsefulObject instance = // new UsefulObjectSimpleImplementation(); 
                              AndroidMock.createNiceMock(UsefulObject.class);           
      MyModule mockModule = new MyModule();
      mockModule.setUsefulObject(instance);
      MyApplication.setModule(mockModule);
      super.setUp();
  }

  // Make sure you use one of the @*Test annotations AND begin
  // your testcase's name with "test"
  @MediumTest
  public void test01() {
      AndroidMock.expect(MyApplication.getModule().getUsefulObject().
           simpleMethod()).andStubReturn("Hello!");
  }
  ```

  }
- Ensure that for the test project, the AndroidManifest.xml file has the following entry:

> ```
>    <instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
>      android:targetPackage="com.mypackage"
>      android:label="Tests for com.mypackage"/>
> ```

- Before running your test, ensure your emulator is started and is running healthily, by running a different, simple "Hello World" app first.  When this succeeds, then run your app.  Lastly, run your test project.

Should work after this.  Best of luck & let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a bug in Android itself. See the [bug report here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24846). The VM crashes when it tries to look for annotations on a [Proxy](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), which is what AndroidMock uses when [mocking an interface](https://code.google.com/p/android-mock/wiki/WritingTestsUsingAndroidMock#Creating_the_Mock).

The workaround is to create in instance of a class that implements the interface, as you pointed out in your question. You could try making a pure abstract class that implements the interface without implementing any methods, then use AndroidMock to mock that class instead of the interface. This should avoid the creation of a Proxy.